# How to add right-click popup menu in jTable row?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, menu, jtable

I have a simple code for <kbd>Add</kbd> button like this :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    dtm.addRow (new Object[] {name.getText(),mobile.getText()});    
}
```

This code will get text from `JTextField` and insert into `JTable` row

I want to add function right-click popup menu when i right-click on table row, and add some like <kbd>add</kbd> <kbd>delete</kbd> <kbd>rename</kbd>.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Bring up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for the basics of displaying a menu and a working demo.
2. In the case of a JTable, you will probably want to highlight the row that was clicked on so your Actions can act on the selected row.

So you would need to add code like the following to the `maybeShowPopup(...)` method from the demo example in the tutorial:

```
    if (e.isPopupTrigger())
    {
        JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = source.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
        int column = source.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );

        if (! source.isRowSelected(row))
            source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

        popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
```